# Excel celda con una lista de más de 50 opciones en validacion de datos

Tags: excel

Hola a todos quiero crear en excel una celda que contenga una lista que tiene más de 50 opciones, el problema es que por validacion de datos solo acepta hasta 255 caracteres y solo me acepta las primeras 20 opciones. Tambien tiene que ser separadas por (;) no puede ser a través de un rando de celdas. He intentado con macros en VBA de la siguiente forma pero presenta el mismo problema, cuando guardo el documento que lo vuelvo abrir me dice que hay problemas y cuando lo corrige me elimina todo el listado.
Este es el codigo en VBA:

```
Sub lista()
  Range("B9").Select
  With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, "azul claro,azul oscuro"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = False
  End With
End Sub
```

Por supuesto la lista es mucho más grande de mas de 50 opciones.

Gracias de antemano, si alguien me puede ayudar , se lo agredesco.
Tengan un buen día.

Comment: ¿Por qué no puede ser desde un rango de celdas?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que has dicho que no puede ser mediante un rango de datos, pero la cuestión es, ¿ hay una buena razón para que tenga que ser así.?

Menciono esto porque esa es la forma mas sencilla de hacerlo, regularmente no es necesario tener que usar una macro para algo tan simple.

Si escribes los datos directo en el cuadro de dialogo de la validación, el limite es de 256 caracteres como tu lo has indicado ( incluyendo el separador ), eso mismo aplica cuando usas ese mismo método de validación pero con vba, precisamente como tu código, por eso igual te da el error.

En cambio, si usas el método de rango, el limite es de 32,767 elementos.

Como puedes ver, la mejor opción es trabajar con un rango de datos que contiene tu lista, de hecho puedes hacer referencia a ese rango desde el mismo código vba que has puesto, quedaría algo como esto:

```
.Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, Range("Lista")
```

`Lista` es el nombre que le puedes dar el rango que contiene la lista, de ese modo es mas simple referirse al mismo ya sea en el código o en una formula.

si lo que quieres es proteger esa lista, puedes ocultar la hoja poniendo la propiedad "`visible`" como "`xlSheetVeryHidden`" de dicha hoja.

Lo anterior se puede hacer desde el el explorador del proyecto vba, simplemente seleccionas la hoja en cuestión (estando en la ventana de vba ) y le das el valor "`xlSheetVeryHidden`" a la propiedad "`visible`", de este modo esa hoja no se puede hacer visible desde excel, solo se puede hacer desde el la ventana de vba, pero puedes proteger tu proyecto vba para evitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a imaginar que quieres todo en hojas aparte apara que sea fácil de tener los datos en orden y que no se manipule la información:

Nombres de las hojas en el libro de Excel:

`shtListas`: aquí ponemos nuestra(s) listas

`shtFormulas`: aquí vamos a poner unas formulas que vamos a necesitar para tomar las listas

`shtDatos`: Aquí ponemos todo lo que requerimos

**shtListas**: 
Aquí agregamos en un rango (ya sea en una columna o una fila) todos los datos que ocupamos en nuestra lista, sin restricción de tamaño. Es muy importante respetar que sean una sola columna o una sola fila. Para este ejemplo voy a usar solo una columna. 
A1:A2015

**shtFormulas**: 
Vamos a llenar las siguientes celdas con los valores/formulas:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| A1 | oLista                                                                  | esto es un texto    |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| A2 | =ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,"shtListas")&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(shtListas!A:A),1,1,1,) | esto es una formula |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

[ADDRESS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89)

> **Descripción**
>
> Puede usar la función DIRECCIÓN para obtener la dirección
>   de una celda en una hoja de trabajo, dados los números de fila y
>   columna especificados. Por ejemplo, DIRECCIÓN (2,3) devuelve $C$2.
>   Como otro ejemplo, ADDRESS (77,300) devuelve $KN$77. Puede usar otras
>   funciones, como las funciones FILA y COLUMNA, para proporcionar los
>   argumentos de número de fila y columna para la función DIRECCIÓN.

Con la celda `A2` seleccionada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vamos a presionar `CTRL + F3` o vamos al menú `FORMULAS>Define Name>Define Name` como se ve en la foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que aparezca el siguiente asistente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y llenas los campos como se muestra en la foto:

```
Name: oLista
Scope: Workbook
Comment: (es opcional, puede quedar en blanco)
Refers to: =INDIRECT(shtFormulas!$A$2)
```

Name: Este es el nombre que vamos a usar para llamar todo el rango
Refers to: es la formula que vamos a usar para buscar nuestra lista

[INDIRECT FUNCTION](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

En el enlace anterior puedes encontrar información de como funciona la función INDIRECT, pero brevemente explico que, toma un texto como

> '=INDIRECT("B"&A5)
>
> Combina "B" con el valor en la celda A5 el cual es 5. 
>   Esto devuelve una referencia a la celda B5, la cual contiene el valor 62.

Por tanto en nuestro ejercicio estamos tomando el texto (contenido) de la celda A2, y estamos devolviendo el rango shtListas!$A$1:$A$2015 al nombre que estamos definiendo.

**shtDatos**

En esta hoja, en la celda `A1` agregamos la lista de validación con el menú `DATA>DATA VALIDATION>DATA VALIDATION` como se ve en la foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que aparezca el siguiente asistente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí lo único que es determinante es usar el Nombre de rango "oLista" donde dice Source. Para que nuestra lista busque el rango que tenemos en la hoja shtListas

**VBA**

Y para hacerlo con `VBA` tenemos que usar el siguiente código:

```
Sub rangeList()
Range("A1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=oLista" 'Notese que acá agregamos el rango como una formula
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

El codigo es en caso que quieras usar una macro para agregar la lista de validación.

**Ventajas de la lista con los nombres de rango:**

En caso que la lista en la hoja shtListas deba crecer o acortarse, se pueden cambiar los valores sin problema, (ÚNICAMENTE no dejar espacios vacíos entre la lista). Pero así la lista de validación se va actualizar automáticamente.

Hice todo separado solo por una cuestión (muy personal) de orden, pero se puede hacer todo en una sola hoja, de ser necesario.

Comment: Gracias hermano, muy bien explicado al detalle, me sirvió perfecto, el problema era que estoy haciendo un proyecto que necesitaba importar desde excel, pero cuando creaba mi lista por rango de celda me daba error, solo funcionaba cuando la lista era separada por coma. Pero ya con tu explicacion resolví el problema. disculpame la demora en responderte, y gracias por tomarte el trabajo.